# CSS style does not appear when I deploy on GitHub

Tags: html, css, github

I have a familiar problem

when I deploy on GitHub does not appear style

but it works fine on live server (vs code)

repository:
https://github.com/Odai-AbuSnineh/my-restaurant/

live site:
https://odai-abusnineh.github.io/my-restaurant/

Does anyone know the solution?

I tried to solve it but it still did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using absolute paths to all your files.

When you use `<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="/style.css">` on this URL: https://odai-abusnineh.github.io/my-restaurant/ then the path to that CSS file is wrong.

It ends up being `https://odai-abusnineh.github.io/styles.css` instead of `https://odai-abusnineh.github.io/my-restaurant/styles.css`

Just remove that `/` from your link and that should fix it. Like this:

`<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="style.css">`

The same goes for all of your images too.